# Swift Argument labels '(_:, destination:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift

Im converted project to Swift 4.1 and have error when trying to remake

```
 private func download(downloadable: Downloadable, destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination) -> Request {
        var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask!
        switch downloadable {
        case .Request(let request):
            dispatch_sync(queue) {
                downloadTask = self.session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request)
            }
        case .ResumeData(let resumeData):
            dispatch_sync(queue) {
                downloadTask = self.session.downloadTaskWithResumeData(resumeData)
            }
        }
        let request = Request(session: session, task: downloadTask)
        if let downloadDelegate = request.delegate as? Request.DownloadTaskDelegate {
            downloadDelegate.downloadTaskDidFinishDownloadingToURL = { session, downloadTask, URL in
                return destination(URL, downloadTask.response as! NSHTTPURLResponse)
            }
        }
        delegate[request.delegate.task] = request.delegate
        if startRequestsImmediately {
            request.resume()
        }
        return request
    }
```

and

```
public func download(
    method: Method,
    _ URLString: URLStringConvertible,
    parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL,
    headers: [String: String]? = nil,
    destination: Request.DownloadFileDestination)
    -> Request
{
    let mutableURLRequest = URLRequest(method: method, URLString, headers: headers)
    let encodedURLRequest = encoding.encode(URLRequest: mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    return download(encodedURLRequest, destination: destination)
}
```

And when I call

Error :

> Argument labels '(_:, destination:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: Did you mean to call the function `download1` rather than `download` ?

Comment: The error is clear. Your `download` function has different parameters from the ones you are trying to pass in. Perhaps you meant to call `download1`?

Comment: Yes, I fix question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `download` function has that signature shown in the error.

You either call the first `download` as:

```
let result = download(downloadable: someValue, destination: someOtherValue)
```

Or you call the second `download` as:

```
let result = download(method: someMethod, someURLString, destination: someDestination)
```

And of course that second call can have one or more of the optional parameters too.

Most likely you want to change:

```
return download(encodedURLRequest, destination: destination)
```

to:

```
return download(downloadable: encodedURLRequest, destination: destination)
```

This assumes that `encodedURLRequest` is of type `Downloadable`.

Comment: when I call         `return download(downloadable: encodedURLRequest, destination: destination)`  it's give me  `Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableURLRequest' to expected argument type 'Manager.Downloadable'`

Comment: Which was mentioned in the very last sentence of my answer. You need to pass the correct type to each parameter.